# How much does a bludger weigh?

Tags: harry-potter, quidditch

Harry Potter wikia has an [article on the bludger](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Bludger), which suggests the weight of the bludger to be 149 lb (65 kg), under the assumption they are made of pure iron. Yet in the first movie of the series, Harry Potter, aged 11, manages to deflect one travelling fast towards him, with what appears to be bat weighing no more than 1 kg, one-handed.

Comment: I haven't the foggiest where the wikia got the idea that Bludgers are made of iron from, but if it turns out to be true, I'll be amazed

Comment: @Au101 *Quidditch Through the Ages* says that bludgers are made of iron. It doesn't specify a weight, or even that they need be pure or solid iron, though

Comment: Harry Potter Wiki = World Wide Web of lies.

Comment: What do you know, *Quidditch Through the Ages* does claim they're made of iron, but they surely can't be exclusively iron, if they are I think you'll have to add medicine, physics and materials science to maths in the list of JKR's bogey subjects :S

Comment: @JasonBaker Yeah... Well, I'm off to buy a new hat ... ;)

Comment: As regards the bat, the same article does say that the beaters’ bats are “magically reinforced”… which they’d bloody well have to be if they’re to be any use against a 10-inch solid iron ball. I think we’ll have to assume that the _Quidditch through the Ages_ quote only implies that they’re **partially** made of iron, with other stuff mixed in as well.

Comment: The bats might be magically reinforced, but that will only do so much if the people aren't.  I think it would have to be hollow (and probably quite thin), for there to be any playability - acceleration can generate a lot of force on its own, add any appreciable mass and it would quickly be a case that a solid hit would break the player's hand, arm or shoulder (bat being "magically reinforced") instead of altering the course of the bludger.

Comment: "Quidditch teams began experimenting with metal Bludgers in the early sixteenth century. Agatha Chubb, expert in ancient wizarding artifacts, has identified no fewer than twelve lead Bludgers dating from this period, discovered both in Irish peat bogs and English marshes. "They are undoubtedly Bludgers rather than cannon balls," she writes.

The faint indentation of magically reinforced Beaters' bats are visible and one can see the distinctive hallmarks of manufacture by a wizard (as opposed to a Muggle) - the smoothness of line, the perfect symmetry. (continues)

Comment: "(...) Nowadays all Bludgers are made of iron. They are ten inches in diameter." [Quidditch through the times]  If bludgers look so close to cannonballs, I would say they are indeed a 10-inch solid metal balls.

Comment: In the book the bludger only breaks Harry's arm. But in the movie, it bashes through some VERY thick support pillars of the viewers' pavilion, without noticeably slowing down. In that case it very much seems 150 pounds is a believable figure.

Answer (score 6):

### Weight Calculation One

based on Harry's observation as described in *"Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone"*

Here some info about the size of the Bludger:

> "Three Chasers," Harry repeated, as Wood took out a **bright red ball
> about the size of a soccer ball.**
>
> "**This ball's called the Quaffle,**" said Wood. "The Chasers throw the
> Quaffle to each other and try and get it through one of the hoops to
> score a goal. Ten points every time the Quaffle goes through one of
> the hoops. Follow me?"

and

> "I'm going to show you what the Bludgers do," Wood said. "**These two
> are the Bludgers.**"
>
> He showed Harry two identical balls, jet black and **slightly smaller
> than the red Quaffle.** Harry noticed that they seemed to be straining
> to escape the straps holding them inside the box.

So a Bludger is slightly smaller than a soccer ball.

The soccer ball's volume is around 0.00558 cubic meters (assuming official FIFA rules for average circumference of 69 cm).

"Slightly" is not a very precise definition but it implies that the size difference is visible. So a Bludger is at least 10% - 20% smaller than the Quaffle.

Based on that - a Bludger made of pure iron will weight about 35 - 40 kg.

### Weight Calculation Two

Based on "Quidditch Through the Ages"

As mentioned by @DavidBanner in the comments - "Quidditch Through the Ages" explicitly mentions the size of the Bludger - 10 inches or 25,4 cm diameter.
This is actually bigger than a soccer ball (and the Quaffle is much bigger).

Then the pure iron-made Bludger would weight about 67 kg.

So the wiki article most probably used the second calculation for the weight.

### Does it really weight that much?

I find it unlikely for several reasons:

- Considering the speed described in the books, a hit from a Bludger will kill or at least seriously injure the player.
- Wood carries TWO Bludgers, the Quaffle and the Snitch in a crate "under his arm". Carrying something that weights between 80 and 140 kg like this requires significant strength and even then can't be done for a long. Magic might be involved of course to make the crate weight less.
- As noted in the comments - a Bludger of this weight will break the bat of the Beater unless it is magically enchanted.

The main idea of the Bludgers are to distract and knock off players, not to kill them. Making them heavy and enchanting everything around them to adjust to this weight makes little sense.

So most likely Bludgers weight around 1-2 kg - enough to make a painful hit (or break your arm if hitting on the right place) but not to do much more harm.

Comment: Don't forget - JKR math.

Comment: According to Quidditch through the times, a quaffle is 12 inches in diameter and a Bludger is 10 inches.

Comment: @DavidBanner  thanks - I'll correct the calculations

Comment: On the novels they say that the bludgers are made of iron, not that they are FULL of solid iron. Maybe they are just an empty sphere of iron, which, probably, will weight about 2.5 kgs.

Comment: @Bardo - this is possible although to make a sphere of iron that big, weight about 2.5 kg, the iron should be around 1.5 - 2mm thin. As a result the Bludgers will bent a lot when hit. Again it might be magic involved to prevent that.

Comment: @vap78 seems a lot easier and practical than create a monster of 65+ kgs and magically adequate everything in its surroundings to make them not lethal